# Play sound anywhere in project

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there a way to play a sound anywhere in your project with just 1 declaration. I just want to declare it once, and then in any class just call like, pop.play or something. It looks really messy using the same sound instantiation code in every class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

create an extension of UIViewController and place the code there.
Keeps this extention in a separate file.

```
extension UIViewController { //urcode }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can
Just make `extension`
Example, my function that make circle `UIView`:

```
extension UIViewController {
func makeCircle(view: UIView){
        view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width/2
        view.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    }
```

Then you can call this function everywhere in your project
Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    makeCircle(view: yourView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a protocol and any class or struct you need the play a sound function you conform to the protocol. You can additionally add a base implementation to the playSound function in the protocol extension.

```
protocol Sound {
    func playSound()
}

extension Sound {
    func playSound() {
        /// implementation
    }
}
```